# Problem extracting text from h1 tag Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm a complete newbie to parsing websites but I've had a script that pulls the figures of different housing sites which worked flawlessly for the past year. However, for a reason I can't figure out, it no longer works on daft.ie anymore. I've tried to debug but nothing I try seems to work. I either get 'list index out of range' or 'None' which I know it indicates the array is empty but its clearly not. Below is a snippet of the problem-some code.

Would appreciate someone who has more knowledge than I to have a look as I'm sure its going to be something which should be obvious.

Appreciate all the assistance from the site.

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_buy_numbers_dublin_city():
    page = requests.get("https://www.daft.ie/property-for-sale/dublin-city")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    prop_num = str(soup.find_all(class_="styles__SearchH1-sc-1t5gb6v-3 guZHZl")[0])
    prop_num = prop_num.replace('<h1 class="styles__SearchH1-sc-1t5gb6v-3 guZHZl" data-testid="search-h1">', '')
    prop_num = prop_num.replace(' Properties for Sale in Dublin City</h1>', '')
    prop_num = prop_num.replace(',', '')
    return(prop_num)

def main(argv):

    print(get_buy_numbers_dublin_city())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: _I know it indicates the array is empty but its clearly not_ Why do you say "it's clearly not"?  How do you know it's not empty?

Comment: Also, please include the full error traceback message so we don't have to guess where the error happens.

Comment: The error is:
prop_num = str(soup.find_all(class_="styles__SearchH1-sc-1t5gb6v-3 guZHZl")[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

I also tried with lxml and it gave me 'None' type for the array so I just assumed it was being seen as empty.

Comment: `soup.find_all(class_="styles__SearchH1-sc-1t5gb6v-3 guZHZl")` did not find any matching html elements on that page.  Perhaps the website was updated or redesigned and it no longer uses that specific class name.

Comment: it means that it doesn't find any classes. I beleive you need to replace space by dots when refering to multiple classes. so soup.find_all(class_=".styles__SearchH1-sc-1t5gb6v-3.guZHZl")[0], maybe?

Comment: Thanks all but as I described above, this code worked for the past year until very recently. I assumed when it broke that the elements maybe just changed but thats not the case. The class is still the same name. You can quickly search the class in the source code. I tried removing spaces and '=' too but it didn't work either. :/

Comment: It looks like the website was redesigned to use javascript, and unfortunately `requests` cannot process javascript.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon. I was thinking this might be the issue. Any ideas what I could use as a potential get around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue would be that this site is also protecting its content, so you always should take a closer look into response text or `soup`, because in this case non of the content you would expect is in the HTML.

You could add an `user-agent` to avoid these behavior for some time or use `selenium` and co. to mimic browser. Be aware that if some other of your scraping behavior is detected, server may block you again.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.daft.ie/property-for-sale/dublin-city", headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

print(soup.h1.text.split()[0])
```

Will give you:

```
2,544
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was suspecting requests was being blocked but I wasn't sure how to test the theory. I should have used Selenium but it never even dawned on me. Your solution is much better for my use case though so thank you for that. 
Small modification: I had to add ', "html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor to avoid getting an error in Pycharm. Still worked though.